# LSTM model classify only 1 class in multi class classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I wrote python code for imbalanced multi-class classification of Rainfall Dataset using LSTM input variables are a numeric form of temperature, sunshine and humidity the target has four classes no-rain,light-rain, moderate and heavy-rain but the model classifies only one class at the confusion matrix as shown in the following code.

I have Also try SMOTE and class weight techniques to balance the class but the result is not changed.

Can anyone help me full LSTM code for imbalanced multiclass classification?

Confusion Matrix

[image]
Dataset screenshot

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.utils import resample
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from numpy import array
from numpy import argmax
from pylab import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
from keras.regularizers import l1,l2,l1_l2
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler, MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, SimpleRNN, LSTM, Dropout, GRU, Bidirectional, Activation
from scipy import stats
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from imblearn.combine import SMOTETomek
from imblearn.under_sampling import NearMiss
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format='retina'
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from dateutil.parser import parse
register_matplotlib_converters()
sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette='muted', font_scale=1.5)
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 22, 10
RANDOM_SEED = 42
np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(RANDOM_SEED)

# load dataset
df = pd.read_csv("Arbaminch_Rainfall_All_In_One_Classiffication.csv")
#df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True, format='%d-%m-%Y', errors='coerce')
#df = df.set_index('Date').rename_axis('Rainfall', axis=1)
df = df.drop('Date', 1)
#df.plot()
df.head()



columns = df.columns.tolist()
# filter the columns to remove data e do not want
columns = [c for c in columns if c not in['Rainfall9AM']]
target = df.Rainfall9AM
state = np.random.RandomState(42)

X = df[columns] # independent Variable
Y = target      # dependent Variable

X.shape, Y.shape

X = X.ffillna(X.mean())
Y= Y.fillna(method='ffill')


from sklearn import preprocessing 
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
Y = label_encoder.fit_transform(Y)
Y = pd.DataFrame(Y)
Y.columns = ['Rainfall9AM']





from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1,stratify=Y)
X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape


#All Varibles
scale_columns = ['MaxTemp6PM', 'MinTemp9AM', 'AVGTemp', 'Sunshine6PM', 'Humidity6AM', 'Humidity9AM', 'Humidity12PM', 
                'Humidity3PM', 'Humidity6PM', 'MaxHumid', 'MinHumid', 'AVGHumid']

# Granger selected features 
#'Rainfall9AM','MaxTemp6PM','Sunshine6PM','Humidity6AM','Humidity12PM',
#    'Humidity6PM','MaxHumid','MinHumid','AVGHumid'

#scale_columns = ['MaxTemp6PM','Sunshine6PM','Humidity6AM','Humidity12PM','Humidity6PM','MaxHumid','MinHumid','AVGHumid']

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
scaler = scaler.fit(X_train[scale_columns])

X_train.loc[:, scale_columns] = scaler.transform(X_train[scale_columns].to_numpy())
X_test.loc[:, scale_columns] = scaler.transform(X_test[scale_columns].to_numpy())




#from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
#classes = np.array([0,1,2,3])
#weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', classes, y_for_train).all()
class_weights = {
    0: 4.,
    1 :5.,
    2 :5.,
    3 :1.
}





#To create 3D for Lstm
def create_dataset(X, y, time_steps=1, step=1):
    Xs, ys = [], []
    for i in range(0, len(X) - time_steps, step):
        v = X.iloc[i:(i + time_steps)].values
        labels = y.iloc[i: i + time_steps]
        Xs.append(v)        
        ys.append(stats.mode(labels)[0][0])
        return np.array(Xs), np.array(ys).reshape(-1, 1)
TIME_STEPS = 30
STEP = 1
X_train, y_train = create_dataset(X_train, y_train, TIME_STEPS, STEP)
X_test, y_test = create_dataset(X_test, y_test, TIME_STEPS, STEP)



# One Hot Encode
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
enc = enc.fit(y_train)
y_train = enc.transform(y_train)
y_test = enc.transform(y_test)



#define model
optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001, momentum= 0.0)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, activation='relu'), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], Activation('softmax'), bias_regularizer=l2(1e-2)))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optimizer, metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()




history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=10,class_weight = class_weights, batch_size=32,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),shuffle=True)


model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
# Creates a confusion matrix
num_classes = 4
y_true = tf.argmax(y_test, axis = 1)
y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis = 1)




cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=[0,1,2,3]) 
cm_df = pd.DataFrame(cm,index = ['No_Rain', 'Light_Rain', 'Moderate', 'Heavy_Rain'], columns = ['No_Rain', 'Light_Rain', 'Moderate', 'Heavy_Rain'])

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
sns.heatmap(cm_df, annot=True, fmt="d", cmap='Blues') 
plt.title('Bidirectional_LSTM_Model\nAccuracy:{0:.3f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)))
plt.ylabel('True Label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Label')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is way too little information to help you. Regarding balance: You can apply methods such as under- oder over-sampling.

Comment: I have Also try SMOTE and class weight techniques to balance the class but the result is not changed.

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't post the code and the data s.t. we can understand or reproduce your problem. Also: Do not post screenshots. Post the actual data.

Comment: I say 
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon. When I copy the code So how can I post The code and the data

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. If you don't understand how simple Markdown works then it might be a bit too early for machine learning.

Comment: Ok I already Posted the code.

Comment: This code is not executable and it's also rather confusing. It looks like you just copy pasted some parts of the code together. Anyway, you need to clean up, post the entire code and some data s.t. we can reproduce this. The other option you have is debug and check whether everything you do behaves as you expect. E.g. are the labels correct etc. I don't see where your data comes from so I have way of telling where you might make an error.

Comment: Can we download the data somewhere? I am not sure what you're doing here. What are you trying to predict? Is it the weather of the next day given 30 days before? I'm not sure if the way you are splitting the data into train/test is what you want. Also, this here could be a problem or maybe even the reason for what your model does: `stats.mode(labels)`.

Comment: Dear  Stefan Falk, Yes, I am trying to predict the next day having previous 30-day input for LSTM that is why I give 30. But  I am not sure whether I am correct or not because I am beginners for deep Learning I expect your advice Thanks. The data is private and I can not post it with StackOverflow If you are will I will attach it with your e-mail.

Comment: Can you confirm that `stats.mode(labels)` in your `create_dataset ()` is actually what you want? Why are you calling `mode()` on your labels? This looks a bit odd to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My belief is that you have some bugs in your code. One thing you didn't explain to me is why you are calling `stats.mode(labels)` on your labels for example. Also, I can't tell whether or not you used SMOTE correctly and so on.

However, since you cannot provide any data here on stackoverflow I took the [Rain in Australia](https://www.kaggle.com/jsphyg/weather-dataset-rattle-package) dataset from Kaggle.

It looks very similar to yours. The big difference is that we have only two classes for "rain tomorrow": `yes` and `no`. But it's also quite imbalanced:

```
yes   77%
no    23%
```

I implemented a simple model with some very lazy preprocessing (so all this can probably improved by *a lot*. However, it should be good enough for you to learn from this example and compare it to yours. Simply download the data [here](https://www.kaggle.com/jsphyg/weather-dataset-rattle-package) and give it a go.

Without any tuning and balancing I am able to get an accuracy of around 82% on the test data. On Kaggle I saw people getting 88% on this so we can definitely improve our model.

All you need to do is make sure that `weatherAUS.csv` is available on your system and that you have Tensorflow (I used 2.4.1) and the other dependencies installed.

After that you should be able to change the code s.t. it runs on *your* dataset. For now, without considering the imbalanced data. Once your model starts predicting something more reasonable, we can try to improve it by employing some balancing techniques.

#### The Code (for weatherAUS.csv)

```py
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


def preprocess(df_, split, num_pipeline, cat_pipeline, targets_encoder, numeric_columns, categorical_columns):
    """Quick, dirty and lazy preprocessing."""
    df_split = df_.loc[split]

    nums = num_pipeline.transform(df_split[numeric_columns])
    cats = cat_pipeline.transform(df_split[categorical_columns].drop(columns='RainTomorrow')).todense()

    df_num = pd.DataFrame(nums, index=df_split[numeric_columns].index, columns=df_split[numeric_columns].columns)
    df_cat = pd.DataFrame(cats, index=df_split[categorical_columns].index, columns=list(np.concatenate(cat_pipeline.categories_)))

    df_X = df_num.join(df_cat).sort_index()

    df_Y = targets_encoder.transform(df_split.RainTomorrow.values.reshape(-1, 1)).todense()
    df_Y = pd.DataFrame(df_Y, index=df_split.index, columns=targets_encoder.categories_[0]).sort_index()

    return df_X, df_Y


def sample_generator(df_X, df_Y, nb_days: int, seed: int = None, max_samples: int = None):
    rnd = np.random.RandomState(seed)
    locations = df_X.index.get_level_values(0)
    loc_indices = list(range(len(locations)))

    count = 0
    while True:

        if max_samples is not None and count >= max_samples:
            break

        count += 1

        # We cannot simply sample a series arbitrarily. Need to make sure
        # that samples come from one particular location (city). Thus, we pic a location first ...
        location = locations[rnd.choice(loc_indices)]

        # .. and now we pick nb_days for that location
        offs = rnd.randint(0, len(df_X.loc[location]) - nb_days)
        start = offs
        end = offs + nb_days

        x = df_X.loc[location].iloc[start:end]
        y = df_Y.loc[location].iloc[end - 1]

        yield x, y


def fill_missing_values(df_raw, numeric_columns, categorical_columns):
    """Quick and dirty missing-value preprocessing."""

    locations = set(df_raw.Location.unique())

    # Fill missing values

    dfs = list()
    for location in locations:
        df_loc = df_raw[df_raw.Location == location].set_index('Date')

        # We resample and interpolate ..
        df_num = df_loc[numeric_columns].resample('1D').mean().interpolate()
        # .. and fill the rest with mean values
        df_num = df_num.fillna(df_num.mean())

        df_cat = df_loc[categorical_columns.union({'Location'})]
        # For categorical features we simple take the mode
        df_cat = df_cat.fillna(df_cat.mode())
        df_ = df_num.join(df_cat)
        df_ = df_.reset_index().set_index(['Location', 'Date'])
        dfs.append(df_)

    df_ = pd.concat(dfs)
    df_ = df_[~df_.RainTomorrow.isnull()]
    # There could still be some missing values. Again, out of laziness, I just fill nan values with averages and modes
    df_num = df_[numeric_columns].fillna(df_[numeric_columns].mean())
    df_cat = df_[categorical_columns]
    df_cat = df_cat.fillna(df_cat.mode().iloc[0])

    df = df_num.join(df_cat)
    df = df[sorted(df.columns)]

    return df


def main():

    file_path = 'weatherAUS.csv'
    assert os.path.exists(file_path), f'Cannot find data-file: {file_path}'

    seed = 42

    df_raw = pd.read_csv(file_path)

    # Convert to datetime
    df_raw.Date = pd.to_datetime(df_raw.Date, infer_datetime_format=True)

    # If a column contains more than 15% null-values we do not consider it as feature.
    # I only do this out of laziness. We could probably do better.
    null_threshold = 0.15
    null_perc = df_raw.isnull().sum() / len(df_raw)
    useful_columns = set(null_perc[null_perc < null_threshold].index)

    # Separate (useful) numeric and categorical columns

    numeric_columns = useful_columns & set(df_raw.select_dtypes(exclude=['object', 'datetime64[ns]']).columns)
    categorical_columns = useful_columns & set(df_raw.select_dtypes(exclude=['float64', 'datetime64[ns]']).columns)
    categorical_columns = categorical_columns - {'Location'}

    df = fill_missing_values(df_raw, numeric_columns=numeric_columns, categorical_columns=categorical_columns)

    # Create train/test split by location

    train, test = train_test_split(df.index.get_level_values(0).unique(), test_size=0.2, random_state=seed)

    # Create preprocessing pipeline for numeric and categorical data

    num_pipeline = StandardScaler()
    num_pipeline.fit(df.loc[train][numeric_columns])

    cat_pipeline = OneHotEncoder()
    cat_pipeline.fit(df.loc[train][categorical_columns].drop(columns='RainTomorrow'))

    # Targets encoder

    targets_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
    targets_encoder.fit(df.loc[train].RainTomorrow.dropna().unique().reshape(-1, 1))

    # Preprocess

    df_train_X, df_train_Y = preprocess(
        df, train,
        num_pipeline=num_pipeline,
        cat_pipeline=cat_pipeline,
        targets_encoder=targets_encoder,
        numeric_columns=numeric_columns,
        categorical_columns=categorical_columns
    )
    df_test_X, df_test_Y = preprocess(
        df, test,
        num_pipeline=num_pipeline,
        cat_pipeline=cat_pipeline,
        targets_encoder=targets_encoder,
        numeric_columns=numeric_columns,
        categorical_columns=categorical_columns
    )

    # Just checking that we have indeed separated locations
    assert len(set(df_train_X.index.get_level_values(0)).intersection(set(df_test_X.index.get_level_values(0)))) == 0

    # Create Tensorflow dataset

    nb_days = 7  # The number of days we consider
    batch_size = 50
    nb_features = len(df_train_X.columns)
    nb_classes = len(targets_encoder.categories_[0])

    train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: sample_generator(df_train_X, df_train_Y, nb_days, seed=seed),
        output_shapes=((None, nb_features), (nb_classes,)),
        output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32)
    ).prefetch(batch_size).padded_batch(batch_size)

    test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: sample_generator(df_test_X, df_test_Y, nb_days, seed=seed, max_samples=1000),
        output_shapes=((None, nb_features), (nb_classes,)),
        output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32)
    ).prefetch(batch_size).padded_batch(batch_size)

    # Create model

    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(None, nb_features,))
    x = inputs
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1))(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.1))(x)
    x = layers.Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics='accuracy'
    )

    # Train

    model.fit(
        train_data,
        epochs=20,
        steps_per_epoch=100,
        validation_data=test_data.repeat(),
        validation_steps=50
    )

    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_data)

    random = (df.RainTomorrow.value_counts() / df.RainTomorrow.value_counts().sum()).max()

    print(f'Accuracy: {100 * accuracy:.2f} %')
    print(f'Random:   {100 * random:.2f} %')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Output

```
Epoch 1/5
100/100 [==============================] - 50s 469ms/step - loss: 0.4868 - accuracy: 0.7843 - val_loss: 0.5015 - val_accuracy: 0.7708
Epoch 2/5
100/100 [==============================] - 45s 459ms/step - loss: 0.4142 - accuracy: 0.8202 - val_loss: 0.4592 - val_accuracy: 0.7972
Epoch 3/5
100/100 [==============================] - 46s 462ms/step - loss: 0.3692 - accuracy: 0.8383 - val_loss: 0.4622 - val_accuracy: 0.8036
Epoch 4/5
100/100 [==============================] - 46s 461ms/step - loss: 0.3535 - accuracy: 0.8469 - val_loss: 0.4463 - val_accuracy: 0.8204
Epoch 5/5
100/100 [==============================] - 46s 463ms/step - loss: 0.3505 - accuracy: 0.8427 - val_loss: 0.4347 - val_accuracy: 0.8132
20/20 [==============================] - 3s 145ms/step - loss: 0.4384 - accuracy: 0.8140
Accuracy: 81.40 %
Random:   77.58 %
```

---

#### Code & Results for OPs Data

> **Note:** The provided dataset was/is very small (~3000 samples).

```py
from operator import itemgetter

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


def preprocess(df: pd.DataFrame, inputs_pipeline, targets_encoder):

    numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns

    inputs = inputs_pipeline.transform(df[numeric_columns])
    targets = targets_encoder.transform(df.Rainfall9AM.values.reshape(-1, 1)).todense()

    df_inputs = pd.DataFrame(inputs, index=df.index, columns=numeric_columns)
    df_targets = pd.DataFrame(targets, index=df.index, columns=targets_encoder.categories_[0])

    return df_inputs, df_targets


def sample_generator(df_inputs: pd.DataFrame, df_targets: pd.DataFrame, nb_days: int, max_samples: int = None, seed=42):

    rnd = np.random.RandomState(seed)
    count = 0

    while True:

        if max_samples is not None and count >= max_samples:
            break

        count += 1

        offs = rnd.randint(0, len(df_inputs) - nb_days)

        start = offs
        end = offs + nb_days

        x = df_inputs.iloc[start:end]
        y = df_targets.iloc[end]

        yield x, y


def fill_missing_values(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Very lazy and dirty preprocessing. Replace this by something more sophisticated."""
    df_targets = df[['Rainfall9AM']]
    df = df.resample('1D').mean().interpolate()
    df = df.fillna(df.mean())
    df = df[sorted(df.columns)]
    df = df.join(df_targets)
    df = df[~df.Rainfall9AM.isnull()]
    df = df.dropna(1)
    assert not df.isnull().any().any()
    df = df.sort_index()
    return df


def get_model(nb_features: int, nb_classes: int):
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(None, nb_features,))
    x = inputs
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1))(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.1))(x)
    x = layers.Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics='accuracy'
    )

    return model


def main():
    fp = 'Arbaminch_Rainfall_Classiffication.csv'

    df_raw = pd.read_csv(fp)

    # Convert to datetime
    df_raw.Date = pd.to_datetime(
        df_raw.Date,
        infer_datetime_format=True,
        # FIXME The provided data contains errors (invalid dates e.g. 2/29/2009)
        errors='coerce'
    )
    df_raw = df_raw.set_index('Date')

    # Fill missing values
    # FIXME The preprocessing is lazy and should be improved!
    df = fill_missing_values(df_raw)

    # Create train/test split

    nb_train = int(len(df) * 0.8)
    df_train_data, df_test_data = df[:nb_train], df[nb_train:]

    print(f'Training samples: {len(df_train_data)}')
    print(f'Test samples:     {len(df_test_data)}')

    # Create preprocessing pipeline for numeric and categorical data

    numeric_columns = df_train_data.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns
    inputs_pipeline = StandardScaler()
    inputs_pipeline.fit(df_train_data[numeric_columns])

    targets_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
    targets_encoder.fit(df_train_data.Rainfall9AM.dropna().unique().reshape(-1, 1))

    # Preprocess

    df_train_X, df_train_Y = preprocess(
        df_train_data,
        inputs_pipeline=inputs_pipeline,
        targets_encoder=targets_encoder
    )

    df_test_X, df_test_Y = preprocess(
        df_test_data,
        inputs_pipeline=inputs_pipeline,
        targets_encoder=targets_encoder
    )

    assert len(set(df_train_X.index.get_level_values(0)).intersection(set(df_test_X.index.get_level_values(0)))) == 0

    # Create Tensorflow dataset

    nb_days = 7
    batch_size = 100
    nb_features = len(df_train_X.columns)
    nb_classes = len(targets_encoder.categories_[0])

    train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: sample_generator(df_train_X, df_train_Y, nb_days=nb_days),
        output_shapes=((None, nb_features), (nb_classes,)),
        output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32)
    ).prefetch(batch_size).padded_batch(batch_size)

    test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: sample_generator(df_test_X, df_test_Y, nb_days=nb_days, max_samples=1000),
        output_shapes=((None, nb_features), (nb_classes,)),
        output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32)
    ).prefetch(batch_size).padded_batch(batch_size)

    # Get model

    model = get_model(nb_features=nb_features, nb_classes=nb_classes)

    # Start training

    class_names = list(targets_encoder.categories_[0])
    class_counts = dict(df_train_data.Rainfall9AM.value_counts())
    total = float(len(df_train_data))
    class_weight = dict([(i, np.log(total / class_counts[cname])) for i, cname in enumerate(class_names)])

    model.fit(
        train_data,
        epochs=5,
        steps_per_epoch=100,
        validation_data=test_data.repeat(),
        validation_steps=50,
        class_weight=class_weight
    )

    # Evaluate model

    y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(test_data), axis=1)
    y_true = np.argmax(np.concatenate(list(map(itemgetter(1), list(test_data)))), axis=1)

    confusion = pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred), index=class_names, columns=class_names)

    plt.figure()
    sns.heatmap(confusion, annot=True, fmt='d')
    plt.show()

    print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=class_names))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

  Heavy_Rain       0.25      0.25      0.25       170
  Light_Rain       0.12      0.31      0.17       126
    Moderate       0.18      0.37      0.24       140
     No_Rain       0.79      0.30      0.43       564

    accuracy                           0.30      1000
   macro avg       0.33      0.31      0.27      1000
weighted avg       0.53      0.30      0.34      1000
```

Comment: Thanks, Stefen for your help but all my independent variables are numeric-only the targets variable that is rainfall9AM is categorical So if possible pls share the LSTM code that classifies imbalanced multiclass and fits my data Thanks. For that, I think the Iris flower classification is almost similar to my data here is the link for Iris kaggle.com/uciml/iris. or I can send the full dataset if you link your E-mail pls because I can not post in stackoverflow .

Comment: If you look at my code (or run it) you will see that `df.RainTomorrow` is also a categorical variable. My `df.RainTomorrow` has two classes `yes` and `no`. Also, the dataset is imbalanced like yours and does exactly what you are asking for. The Iris flower dataset is different because it does not contain time-series and you would not use an LSTM on that.

Comment: Like I said: You have most likely an error in your code. Did you count the number of occurrences for each class? Don't you think it is strange that your model only predicts `Moderate`? I assume that `No_Rain` is the most frequent. And once again: Why are you calling `stats.mode()` on your `labels` in `create_dataset()`? I implemented the example above s.t. you can run and study it. Try to understand what's happening there and you should be able to change the code s.t. it works on your dataset.

Comment: Yes I count the number of occurrences your assumption is correct when I count no_rain(2252), heavy_rain(568), mderate(451) and light _rain is(405) which becomes a total record of 3676 from the whole 3937 others are missing values . And I don't know deeply how stats.mode() work just I adapt it from other source to create 3D for LSTM thats why I need advice weather  I am correct or not  Thanks .

Comment: Again I ask you is that how can I share you the whole Dataset pls? .  Because if you see the dataset you can understand the problem more . So pls send me your e-mail if possible .

Comment: I am absolutely willing to help you but you have to do your part as well here. I do not need your data because I _know_ that my code, with a few changes, would work on your data exactly the same. If you don't know what `stats.mode()` does, then this is probably one or your errors. `mode()` simple returns you the number that is occurring most often. So I am very confident this it _not_ what you want for your targets. Further, the fact that your confusion matrix only shows a high count for `Moderate` is another indicator that there is something else wrong in your code.

Comment: If you want to train a model you really need to understand what date you are presenting to the data and it seems to me that this is not the case. So, my advice to you, since this is not a lot of code: Start from scratch and make sure that `create_data()` creates the correct data you need for this task. My code is working so you can simply run and debug it and see how it works. All I am doing is I extract `nb_days` from a `Location` and let the model predict `RainTomorrow`.

Comment: This is the same what you want with your data. You also want to take `nb_days` and predict the value of `Rainfall9am` of the next day. So, the only slight difference here is how we _prepare_ the data but everything else is similar. I want to leave this task to you as I have the impression you really should do this by yourself because it is the best way to learn this.

Comment: Ok if so Let me try again but still I am trying to debug it however, it doesn't work for me let me try again Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to run my code and reproduce the model that I have. From there you would only need to apply a few changes s.t. it works for your data. Should you have troubles you can write me again and I'll see how I can help you.

Comment: I have tried by substitute my dataset and when I run the   code it throughout the following error and I cant fix it . TypeError  not supported between instances of int and Timestamp.

Comment: You could provide me a download link to a subset of your dataset (it should be large enough though). You can remove the download link after I got the data. But I have to ask: Why are you working on this? It appears to me that you are not a very experience Python developer. If you are unable to fix a `TypeError` then you should probably focus on Python basics. So, is this a homework or what is all this about?